# How to use e.preventDefault() on $(this) inside the $(window).resize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can I use `$(this).e.preventDefault()` ?

What I want / need is on window resize the `<a>` should behave differently. So like in the fiddle example if window Width is smaller than 710 the `href` should not be triggered. There will only be some JavaScript function toggling the `subnav`. But if window is wider than 710px, I want the `href` to work "normally".

Now with setting up the example I've seen the event is firing multiple times. How can I do it that if fires only once?

Also, is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Please resize window in jsfiddle before clicking! [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2E8eH/)

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var wW = $(window).width();
    $('.windowWidth span').html(wW);
    if(wW < 710) {
        $('nav ul.nav > li > a').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("here");
        });
    } else {
        $('nav ul.nav > li > a').on('click',function(e){
            alert("there");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what you have is pretty much doing that. $(this)'s event handler is being default prevented.

Comment: Do not bind click inside resize, it will cause multiple event handlers on the same element. Do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2E8eH/3/

Comment: @Anton thank you, sorry havent seen your comment before. that would of been the answer! even faster than Rory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the window width within the click handler instead of setting the click handler in the window resize handler. Try this:

```
$('nav ul.nav > li > a').on('click',function(e){
    if ($(window).width() < 710) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    alert("there");
});
```

Your current method will not work as you will end up assigning the same click handler to the same element multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I use $(this).e.preventDefault() ?

You cannot because `.preventDefault()` is a function of `event` property.

However, you can check for `e.target.id` ( *gives you the id of element, which triggered the event*) and see then do something accordingly

Comment: but in jsfiddle, after resizing the window and clicking on a link, it is alerting "here" six times or so, why not only once?